# How do I count ordered tuples in this inequality?

Tags: combinatorics

I have trouble seeing how the total number of k-tuples $(\phi_1 , \phi_2 ,..., \phi_k)$ satisfying the inequality

$1 \leq \phi_1 < \phi_2 < ... < \phi_k \leq n \qquad $  with $k \leq n$

is $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}$.

Can someone shed some light on this by suggesting a combinatorial argument or some other suitable alternative? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only 1 way to order a k-tuple in increasing order

Comment: Thanks, annoyingly that was all that kept me back from understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Identify such a sequence $(\phi_1,\phi_2,\dots,\phi_n)$ with a sequence $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ of $n-k$ zeroes and $k$ ones with the $a_{\phi_i} = 1$ and the others $0$.